# combine text files column wise

Tags: python, excel, text-files, multiple-columns

I have many text files (1,409) with 259,200 x 1 data points (each text file is a year and variable). I want to combine these into one text file column wise, i.e.

```
botTemp_1950 | botTemp_1951 | botTemp_1952 | ... etc
....           ....           .... 
.
.
.
```

I have already done this but the data is arranged into 1 column and is 4GB in size. Is there a way of doing this but column wise in windows, or will I need a scripting language like Python?

I then want to mask the data for only 200 or so rows for each column and take the average for each column so I have a time series for each variable.

If I can do both of these things then ideal, but mainly after the column-wise then I can apply the mask fairly easily in Excel, providing I can open the text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do the whole thing in Excel - A simple VBA for loop where you read in each text file and output it to the next column... By default, each new line in a text file becomes a new row, so it should be fairly straightforward....

Comment: Sounds to me like you would end up with a 1,409 column x 1 row file instead of a 1 column x 1,409 row file. So the part about "want to mask the data for only 200 or so rows for each column" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can try the following:

```
os.chdir(current_dir_with_txt_files)
txtfiles = [open(i) for i in os.listdir('*.txt')]

out = open(out_name, 'w')

from itertools import izip
for l1,l2,l3 in izip(*txtfiles):
    out.write(','.join(l1.strip(), l2.strip(), l3.strip() + '\n')
out.close()
```

This may take a while but it will not consume all your RAM memory.

Comment: Thanks @Saullo, I cannot seem to get this to work after the first line, i.e.:

Comment: txtfiles = [open(i) for i in os.listdir('*.txt')]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    txtfiles = [open(i) for i in os.listdir('*.txt')]
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '*.txt/*.*'

Comment: this error is because the file name is incorrect, try to change it according to your folder structure